# Very strange conversion behavior in JSF application

Tags: jsf

Today I've noticed a very strange conversion behavior in my JSF application. Please have a look at this:

I have this CRUD base class that is intended to be extended by some concrete managed bean classes:

```
public abstract class Cadastro<T, C extends Number> implements Serializable
{
    // _chave is the primary key
    private C _chave;
    // more fields...

    public C getChave()
    {
        return _chave;
    }

    public void setChave(C chave)
    {
        _chave = chave;
        if (_chave != null)
        {
            // More about this below...
            System.out.println(_chave.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    // more methods...
}
```

This is a concrete managed bean class that extends the previous class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroArquivos extends Cadastro<Arquivo, Short>
{
}
```

Note the *Short* type for the primary key.

In the page I have an input text component for the key with a *Short* converter attached to it:

```
<h:inputText value="#{cadastroArquivos.chave}">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Short" />
</h:inputText>
```

So, as you can see, in the java side the *_chave* field has type *Short* in the *CadastroArquivos* class and in the page side there's a *Short* converter that matches this type. But when the page is posted back to the server, the *System.out.println* above prints for the *_chave* class:

***java.lang.Long***

and not *java.lang.Short*. How can it be?

Also, if I change the *CadastroArquivos* class to this to force even more the right conversion:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroArquivos extends Cadastro<Arquivo, Short>
{
    @Override
    public Short getChave()
    {
        return super.getChave();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChave(Short chave)
    {
        super.setChave(chave);
    }
}
```

I get a *ClassCastException*:

*value="#{cadastroArquivos.chave}": java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Short*

But if I change the declaration of the *Cadastro* class to this (note the *C* doesn't extend *Number* anymore):

```
public abstract class Cadastro<T, C> implements Serializable
```

everything works fine, at the cost of making my application less type safe in the java side. Can someone explain to me what's going on and how I can solve this?

Thank you.

Marcos

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using JSF 2.0 in JBoss 6.

Comment: On your 1st implementation, when ´C´ extends Number, its clear you won't be able to obtain a Short from it, however it does not explain why the converter is returning ´Long´ instead of ´Short´, very strange indeed

Comment: of course I won't obtain a Short from the first implementation, because it's an abstract class. The class being used by JSF is the CadastroArquivos class (at least that's what I think), where Short is provided. I'm also using a Short converter in the page to make things even more strange as why I'm getting a Long instead of a Short. As I said, when I change from _C extends Number_ to _C_, I get a Short value and I don't even need to override the getter/setter methods in the subclass. This is really very weird. This is a very easy scenario if someone want to test and make his/her own conclusion

Comment: I kept testing and noticed that when the h:inputText value is left blank I get a _java.lang.Long_. When a value is provided I get a _java.lang.Short_. I still don't understand why a _java.lang.Long_ value is being pushed when a value is not suplied. Any ideas?